# Javascript - Async/Await + .then

Tags: javascript, async-await

Could you confirm a couple of queries for me, please. The first code below is to handle asyncronous data using standard promises:

```
export const fetchData = () => {
  try {
    // const response = await fetch(url)
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

The code below uses the ES7 method using async/await:

```
export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Now, I've seen a variation on both as shown below. Could you confirm if that's just someone perhaps being a little confused or could there be a genuine reason to mix the two together (async/await + .then). While it works ok, one should probably stick to one method, shouldn't they?

```
export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: That last piece of code is definetly wrong, as console.log doesnt return anything

Comment: You're right, one should stick to one method. I do think the bottom one is hypothetically effectively the same though, I just wouldn't recommend doing it because you might as well just stick to `async/await` and not use promises like that in an async function

Comment: @DownloadPizza I think none of them will return anything as 'url' is empty.

Comment: @DownloadPizza I don't think it's "wrong". As far as I can tell, it would behave the same

Comment: Yes, but binding the value to `const response` implies intent to use the json

Comment: @DownloadPizza It is not wrong; `console.log` returns `undefined`. There are no functions in JavaScript that do not produce a value. It _is_ misleading, though. `const foo = undefined` is valid, just not very useful.

Comment: @TKoL That's what I thought. I just wanted to double check it.

Comment: @DownloadPizza it's not returned by the function, so `const response` is just a throwaway variable.

Comment: I dont mean it doesnt run, in js most things run. I mean it doesnt do what OP is obviously trying to do by binding the value

Comment: I don't see a genuine reason, but maybe someone wants to keep the operation that depends on the `data` in `then()` & the other statements that are not directly depend on the `data` put in a synchronous like code to make the code clear.